# ObserveEvent in shiny app does not work with fileInput

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming, alert, shinyalert

my shiny example does not work with the `observeEvent` and I don't know how to fix it !

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File"),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("contents")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  myfile <- reactive({
    
    if(is.null(input$file1)){return(NULL)}
    f = read.csv(input$file1$datapath, header = input$header)
    print(nrow(f))
    return(f)
  })
  observeEvent(input$file1,{

    if (nrow(myfile()) > 100){
    shinyalert("error","file too long",type = "error")
      }
  },ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
  output$contents <- renderTable({
 myfile()
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I know that can be replaced by something like `validate` instead of `shinyalrert` and `observeEvent`, but I'm looking for a solution with `observeEvent`!

Comment: In your observeEvent nrow(myfile()) will generate an error if nothing in it (ie NULL). Add `!is.null(myfile()) &&` before `nrow(myfile())>100` and it should work

Comment: It looks like you don't want to observe `input$file1`, you really want to react to updates to `myfile` specifically.  Try getting rid of `observeEvent` and just use `observe` with the same inner logic (no triggering event)